# Eclipse toolbar

Tags: eclipse

I have a strange problem with my eclipse and my toolbar. Straight forward, the toolbar with the play button is hidden.

According to google it should be a "show toolbar" option under the Window menu, but it is not there.

Anyone know how to get my toolbar back?

Answer (score 0):

It's hidden under Window->Customize Perspective (Eclipse Juno). There you can tick the category "launch" and it's sub-entries to get you button back.

Comment: Sorry, its not just the play button, but the whole toolbar.

Comment: Oh, then I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

it is Window menu->show view 
or Window->Customize Perspective
you will find your toolbar options there

Comment: Can not really find how to show the whole toolbar from this suggestion :(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe updating or downloading the latest version can fix your problem